# JPQL subquery with multiple value return

Tags: jpql, criteria-api

I'm a little confused to convert my SQL to criteria query which needs me to get last actual status.

```
    select r.id, s.CODE, rs.CREATE_DATE
from request r
    join request_status rs on r.id = rs.request_id
    join status s on rs.STATUS_ID = s.ID
    join (SELECT rss.REQUEST_ID, max(rss.CREATE_DATE) lastDate
            FROM REQUEST_STATUS rss GROUP BY rss.REQUEST_ID) lastStatus ON r.ID = lastStatus.REQUEST_ID AND rs.CREATE_DATE = lastStatus.lastDate;

@Entity
public class Request {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request", fetch = LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RequestStatus> requestStatuses = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class RequestStatus {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY, optional = false)
    private Request request;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY, optional = false)
    private Status status;
    private OffsetDateTime createDate;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LastRow {

    private UUID id;
    private OffsetDateTime date;
}
```

So, I do like:

```
    public void run() {
    var builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    var query = builder.createQuery(RequestAsCreatedEvent.class);
    var root = query.from(Request.class);
    query.select(builder.construct(RequestAsCreatedEvent.class,
            root.get(Request_.id),
            root.get(Request_.template).get(Template_.id)));

    var subQuery = query.subquery(LastRow.class);
    subQuery.correlate(root);
    var subRoot = subQuery.from(RequestStatus.class);
    subQuery.groupBy(subRoot.get(RequestStatus_.id));
    
    subQuery.select(builder.construct(LastRow.class, subRoot.get(RequestStatus_.request).get(Request_.id),
                    builder.greatest(subRoot.get(RequestStatus_.createDate))));

    entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

And I can't do that because subQuery.select expect Expression, but I need to select multiple values, and I try to do it like root query via object constructor (but it return CompoundSelection)